# What is the SQL statement for subtracting the values of one column of one table from the other table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm writing an SQL statement to *subtract* total_taxes of the **Deduction table** from the total_salary of the **Salary table** in SQL oracle express edition 18c.

```
        update Salary SET Salary.total_salary = Salary.total_salary - Deduction.total_taxes 
    from Salary , Deduction  where Salary.EID = Deduction.EID;
```

> Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not support updating from multiple tables but the following should work

```
update Salary
set total_salary = total_salary -
(
    select total_taxes
    from Deduction
    where Deduction.EID = Salary.EID
);
```